# Covolution of DTFT

Tags: fourier-transform, convolution

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convolution and DTFT](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/6199/convolution-and-dtft)

$x_1(n)=x_2(n)=1$
where $0 ≤ n ≤ N-1$

1)The linear convolution of the signal gives a triangle how you write it in mathematical form?

The DTFT of the signal is given as

$X_1(e^{jw})=X_2(e^{jw})=\pi \sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty \delta(w-2\pi k)+$$ \frac1 {1-e^{jw}}$

How to calculate the $ DTFT^-(X_1(e^{jw}).X_2(e^{jw})?$

Comment: Duplicate of [this previous question](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/6199/235) with the edits requested _there_ included in this new one.

Comment: @heavenhitman Please edit your original question rather than creating a new one.